# What can my ISP know about a website hosted at my house?

Tags: web-hosting, cloudflare, isp, privacy

I am hosting a public website, say example.com, at my house using my home Internet (fyi, the contract allows it). My Internet plan also comes with a static IP. I use CloudFlare to hide the server's real IP address. The site example.com is fully using HTTPS.

My questions are:

1. Can my ISP know that I'm hosting example.com at my house?
2. What can of information can my ISP know about the incoming traffic to example.com? For example, when someone visits `https://example.com/some-page`, can the ISP know the full URL (and even data) or they will only know the domain, or they won't know anything at all?

P/S: I've done a lot of Google searches but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. SNI header for inbound TLS will show the domain. Depending on the web application, if it makes outbound DNS, TLS, HTTP requests etc. it may show what its trying to access as well - hinting at its identity. See: https://tls12.xargs.org/#client-hello/annotated

Requests for details in trying to hide your website's identity from your ISP are not in line with StackExchange.